# Submit form from the outside of form using htmx

Tags: htmx

How to submit a form using submit button or input type submit outside of the form? In HTML It can be done easily using form ID but I didn't find the way to submit the form outside of the form in HTMX?

Can anybody help in this regard?

Answer (score 15):

A couple of ways:

1. Dispatch a submit event to the form using javascript when the button is clicked.
2. Add the `hx-post` attribute on the external button and also add `hx-include="#your-form-id"`. This will include all the inputs within the form in the request.

Comment: thank you for help., `hx-vals` also necessary in my case.

Comment: You would only need to us hx-vals if you wanted to include additional data not already in the form. hx-include should be able to send all form data. Maybe you need to add a wildcard `hx-include="#your-form-id *"`

Comment: It doesn't work, try it

Answer (score 7):

I think you've put `HTMX` attributes inside the `button` or the `input` tag that is used to submit the form, instead of the form itself. Otherwise, there's no difference between form submission in the normal way or the HTMX way!

You can move `hx-` attributes from the `input` (or `button`) tag to your `form` tag. Take a look at this example:

```html
<form id="search-form"
    hx-get="/search" hx-trigger="submit" hx-target="#results-box">
    <input type="text" name="user-email" placeholder="a part of users email">
    <input type="text" name="user-name" placeholder="a part of users name">
</form>
<input type="checkbox" id="au-cbox" name="only-active-users" form="search-form">
<label for="au-cbox">show only active users</label>

<input type="submit" value="look up" form="search-form">

<div id="results-box"></div>
```

In this example, there are two inputs outside the form: a checkbox and the form's submit button. When you click on the `look up` button, `htmx` will send a `GET` request to the `/search` address, containing three query params: (1) `user-mail` (2) `user-name` (3) `only-active-users` (if checked!)

So there are two ways to show a field is contained in a form: (1) put the field inside the form tag or (2) declare the `form` attribute of the input tag.

You can also use the `button` tag instead of `input` for submission:

```
<button type="submit" form="search-form">look up</button>
```